# CSS flex positioning of DIV containers

Tags: css

Can I archive the desired positioning (see comments in code and try different the different width values) with this approach or would I have to work with breakpoints? https://jsfiddle.net/ekca7pjr/ If the screen is small (<=632 px) everything is as it should be. Between 633 and 671 the div container with class='three' breaks to the right of 'two'. However, I have set flex-grow=1 for class 'two', hoping it would eat up the remaining main axis space like it does in case width >= 672. But in the latter case I would like to have THREE centered below ONE, to the left of TWO (in case TWO is higher than ONE. After hours of fiddling I am lost.

```css
.outer {
  /* width: 632px; all correct if TWO breaks*/
  /* width: 633px; THREE should not be to the left of TWO, but stay below centered, like width <= 632 */
  /* width: 672px; ONE should not grow in height and THREE should be centered below ONE, left of TWO */
  width: 632px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
  padding: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.one {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
}

.two {
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  /* try to take all the space such that there is no more space for THREE */
}

.three {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class='outer'>
  <div class='one'>
    ONE<br> Small&nbsp;image
    <br> here
  </div>
  <div class='two'>
    TWO, text, as wide as it gets, to break the whole div block below ONE<br> Probably higher than ONE<br> Really!
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Table</th>
        <th>to</th>
        <th>stay</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>with</td>
        <td>div</td>
        <td>TWO</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    Some more text
  </div>
  <div class='three'>
    THREE
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your criteria is way too specific you'll have to use Media queries.

Comment: @ZohirSalak that what I meant by using breakpoints. I wonder if I could archive this without media queries, just CSS, because these width are not screen specific, but arbitrary, i.e. derived from the actual content width of this example

Comment: Look into [Heydon's Holy Albatross](http://www.heydonworks.com/article/the-flexbox-holy-albatross-reincarnated), you might find what you need in there.

Comment: @chriskirknielsen Good read, thank you,  but not exactly solving my issue.

Comment: If I were you I would use flex-grow, flex-shrink and flex-basis explicitly for all three blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is a solution I found, without floats, just based on flex and media queries. What I don't like:

1. I had to duplicate THREE and use display:none/block
2. I had to utilize media queries
3. I had to manually adjust the breakpoint of the media query to the warp point of the flex container.
4. That adjustment is slightly different for Firefox and Chrome. They don't wrap at the same point, thus there is a small intermediate transition in Firefox.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lj15dyo9/

```
<html>

<body>

<style>

div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 1em;
    padding: 1em;
}
.flexclass {
    display: flex; 
    flex-wrap: wrap; 
    justify-content: center;
}
.outer {
    flex:0 0 auto;
}
.two {
    flex:1 0 210px;
}
.three {
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
}
.three_1 {
    display:none;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) { 
    .flexclass {
        align-items: stretch;
    }
    .one {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .three {
        display:none;
    }
    .three_1 {
        text-align:center;
        display: block;
    }
}
</style>

<div class="flexclass">
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="one">
            IMAGE
        </div>
        <div class="three">
            BUTTON
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="two">
        TWO is a long text and may wrap and span many rows.
    </div>
</div>
<div class="three_1">
    BUTTON (copy)
</div>

</body>
</html>
```